# reference variable dot reference variable = object

Tags: java

[image]

```
class DoublyLinkedList {
private Link first; 
private Link last; 
public DoublyLinkedList() {
first = null; 
last = null;
}

public boolean isEmpty(){
return first == null;
}

public void insertFirst(long dd){
Link newLink = new Link(dd); 

if (isEmpty()) 
  last = newLink; 
else
  first.previous = newLink; 
newLink.next = first; 
first = newLink; 
}


}

class Link {
public long dData; 
public Link next; 

public Link previous; 

public Link(long d)
{
dData = d;
}

public void displayLink(){
System.out.print(dData + " ");
}

}
```

I have another basic question regarding reference variables in Java: 
I am looking at these two classes in the screenshot. As can be seen, two object reference variables are declared in *Link* and in the *DoublyLinkList* classes. In the *DoublyLinkList* class a function creates an object of the *Link* class and then tries to assign the object to the object reference variables. This is where I'm confused, what does *first.previous* mean? i.e. what does it mean to have two **object reference variables** having a dot in between? same as in *newlink.next*? I get it that *object.funcation* or *object.variables* is a way to call functions or access properties, however, reference variable.a reference variable is confusing me.
thanks !

Comment: Why is this not a case of "object.variable"?

Comment: please post your code in the question. attaching Images is not good practice.

Comment: ok, I will. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The "dot" notation is how you access any accessible member of a type referenced by a variable. Any accessible member. What kind of members can a type have? Variables, types, and methods. By the lower-case spelling of `next` we infer that it's neither a type nor a constant. By the absence of parentheses we infer that `next` is not a method. By the lower-case spelling of `first` we infer that `first` is a variable and not a type, so in turn we conclude that `first.next` is an instance variable for the instance pointed to by `first`.

Comment: would require further explanation, if next is neither a type nor method then what is it?  variable.variable is confusing..

Comment: It's a variable, as I just said in the answer you just read. `first.next` is the instance variable of the object pointed to by `first`. If you couldn't refer to variables of an object, there'd be no reason for variables.

Comment: Reference (non-primitive) variables are pointers to objects (or `null`). `first` points to an object of some type, `Link` in your example. Objects of type `Link` have a member variable `next`, which points to an object of some type, presumably `Link`. So `first.next` is a member variable of a `Link` instance that points to another `Link` instance. Read up on pointers in computer programming.

Comment: OK, so in other words it would be like saying the following:                "Instance variables and methods that are accessible to code outside of the class that they are declared in can be referred to by using a qualified name. The qualified name of an instance variable looks like this:
objectReference.variableName".

Comment: That's correct right out of the Tutorial, @ajavabean. We don't often encounter the term "qualified name" for member references, though. The term is usually encountered with package members, as in "fully qualified name" (FQN). The terminology "instance / static variables" is the norm within types. We just get used to referring to such variables via the instance reference or type name. Think - how else would we be able to specify the `bar` member of what `foo` points to than `foo.bar`? What other way could there be?